# Cannot find zendesk library for integration

Tags: android, android-activity, zendesk, zendesk-api

Am trying to integrate Zendesk to my android app but not able to find the library to add the import statements in my `activity` class.

The `gradle` entry looks like:

```
repositories {
   maven { url 'https://zendesk.jfrog.io/zendesk/repo' }
}
...
dependencies {
   implementation group: 'com.zendesk', name: 'support', version: '2.0.0'
}
```

And the activity class:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.expedia.bookings.R;
import com.zendesk.*;   //cannot find com.zendesk

public class AppSupportActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_app_support);

    Zendesk.INSTANCE.init(context, "My ORG URL",  //Cannot find Zendesk
            "APP_KEY",
            "CLIENT_ID");
    Support.INSTANCE.init(Zendesk.INSTANCE);  //error here: cannot find Support

}
```

}

How can I use `zendesk`?  AM new to android and gradle both. Tried building the app and showed the error. Help.

Answer (score 1):

add these to your appgradle file, here you have a github example of the two files you need to set up in order to use zendesk library
[Build Gradle wher you put the info below](https://github.com/zendesk/sdk_demo_app_android/blob/master/app/build.gradle)

```
implementation 'com.zendesk:support:2.0.0'
implementation 'com.zopim.android:sdk:1.3.7.1'
```

[This is where you put zendesk url](https://github.com/zendesk/sdk_demo_app_android/blob/master/build.gradle)

Comment: Getting this error: `Could not find method implementation() for arguments [{group=com.zendesk, name=support, version=2.0.0}] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
`

Comment: @roger_that you already added this? repositories {
maven { url 'https://zendesk.jfrog.io/zendesk/repo' }
} , first do that and sync project, then try adding implementations, also check the answer is edited with a different way to write the implementation

Comment: What will the import statement look like. I am trying to resolve `Zendesk` and `Support`.

Comment: import zendesk.core.Zendesk;  
import zendesk.support.Support; 

Also did you know that if you click the word marked in red, in this case zendesk and press ALT + Enter it will automatically generate the import?  @roger_that

Comment: Ah. I was trying `com.zendesk.*` which was not working.

Comment: lol @roger_that get used to do what i said above, alt + enter and your problems are solved without writing :P

Comment: Yeah. Earlier the project was not syncing so there were no auto imports. Now i can, but again the problem is at the part of initializing zendesk which is giving error according to what I have coded.